# Extract time from .bag file

Tags: ros, python, rosbag, time, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to process some bag files and, while I am able to get the timestamp for each message, I am not able to get the actual time the message was received. Is it possible to get it? I am using the python api and I could not find any documentations, any help is really appreciated! Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199941/extract-time-from-.bag-file/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get that information using the rosbag API. Take a look at the [rosbag Cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) wiki page. The time is in the tuple returned from read_messages().

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-12-25**:
Does the time refer to when rosbag received the message?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-26**:
Yes that does refer to the receive time.

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-12-26**:
Thanks! I did not know that! I should probably delete my answer as it is inaccurate/misleading.

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2014-12-31**:
For some reason I was confused but yes the time is the third item in the tuple returned by read_messages(). Thanks for the help!